# How can I connect my colledge email to Outlook Live?

Tags: email, gmail, client, pop3, webmail

I am a student at Kennesaw State University. The college email is connected with GMail as the web client, but I cant find a way to connect the PoP (or IMAP, even though PoP is the only one Outlook stated) servers to Outlook (or any other clients). I want to do this so I can have one universal client for all of my mail accounts.

There are many... http://www.k-state.edu/its/zimbra/help/email_clients/ol2003.html http://www.k-state.edu/its/zimbra/help/email_clients/ol2007.html
..."official" guides on how to do this, but no one has had any luck. I want to not only receive, but send emails from this account.

Has anyone had any luck doing this (I think some companies use the same google GMail set-up).

I would like to add that there is the same issue with Zimbra.